# equivalent way drawing method to UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext

Tags: ios, swift, calayer, drawrect

I have a swift class that outputs pie chart, I want to take out drawing logic out of drawRect method, since UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext returns nil outside of the draw method I need to change way of drawing my pie chart view,

What is the appropriate way to do this? My PieChart class looks like;

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let context: CGContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
        drawLinearGradient(context)
        drawCenterCircle(context)
        let circle: CAShapeLayer = drawStroke()
        let pathAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
        pathAnimation.duration = percentage
        pathAnimation.toValue = percentage
        pathAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = rendered ? false : (percentageLabel > 20 ? false : true)
        pathAnimation.isAdditive = true
        pathAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
        circle.add(pathAnimation, forKey: "strokeEnd")
}

private func drawLinearGradient(_ context: CGContext) {
    let circlePoint: CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0,
                                     width: bounds.size.width, height: bounds.size.height)
    context.addEllipse(in: circlePoint)
    context.clip()

    let colorSpace: CGColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    let colorArray = [colors.0.cgColor, colors.1.cgColor]
    let colorLocations: [CGFloat] = [0.0, 1.0]
    let gradient = CGGradient(colorsSpace: colorSpace, colors: colorArray as CFArray, locations: colorLocations)

    let startPoint = CGPoint.zero
    let endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.bounds.height)
    context.drawLinearGradient(gradient!,
                                start: startPoint,
                                end: endPoint,
                                options: CGGradientDrawingOptions.drawsAfterEndLocation)


}

private func drawCenterCircle(_ context: CGContext) {
    let circlePoint: CGRect = CGRect(x: arcWidth, y: arcWidth,
                                     width: bounds.size.width-arcWidth*2,
                                     height: bounds.size.height-arcWidth*2)

    context.addEllipse(in: circlePoint)
    UIColor.white.setFill()
    context.fillPath()
}

private func drawStroke() -> CAShapeLayer {
    let circle = CAShapeLayer()
    self.layer.addSublayer(circle)
    return circle
}
```

Comment: did you already try a way? if yes, could you please be more specific what didn't work

Comment: The `draw(rect:)` method *by definition* has it's own context. Have you tried creating a new one?

Comment: Somehow drawRect method visited multiple times in iOS 11(no problem with iOS 10 and 9), I have to move this logic somewhere else other then drawRect.

Answer (score 3):

You can change your code to produce a `UIImage` containing the pie chart, and then place that image inside an image view:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)
let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
// ... here goes your drawing code, just as before
let pieImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
let pieView = UIImageView(image: pieImage)
```

Note that if you need to update the chart very frequently (multiple times per second), this solution might bring a performance penalty because the image creation takes a bit more time then the pure rendering.